# Post variables not displaying correctly in custom function

Tags: functions, customization, loop

There seems to be something wrong with the simple function below, but I can't figure out what it is. It is displaying as the following and I can't figure out why. I know it has something to do with the functions the_ID(), the_title(), and the_permalink(), but I don't know what it is. Sorry if this sounds like a silly question.

```
1http://www.example.com/?p=1Hello world!<h1 class="title" id="post-"><a rel="bookmark" href=""></a></h1>


function basetheme_nodetitle($before_title="",$after_title="",$link = true) {
    /*
     * basetheme_nodetitle() can only be called inside the Loop
     * $before_title is the initial tag in which to wrap your title, usually <h2> or similar.
     * $after_title is the tag after the title, usually </h2> or similar. Only works if $before_title is NOT empty
     * $link is whether or not the title should be linked. Default is true
     */
    if(empty($before_title)){$before_title = '<h1 class="title" id="post-' . the_ID() . '">';$after_title = "</h1>";}
    if($link == false){$beforelink = '';$afterlink = '';}else{$beforelink = '<a rel="bookmark" href="' . the_permalink() . '">';$afterlink = '</a>';}
    echo $before_title . $beforelink . the_title() . $afterlink . $after_title;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insideds of a function is separated from the global things. Therefore the variables, set by other processes are not reachable/useable inside a function until you made them so, with,  for example `global` keyword for a var.

So

Add

```
the_post();
```

after the function's {,

or add

```
global $post;
```

and use `$post->ID` instead of `the_ID` and so on.
I also recommend you to read some books on programming PHP.

Comment: Thank you! I am still quite the noob in php and didn't even know about the $post variable in WordPress.

Comment: In this case I seriously recommend to read through
http://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation